# JQuery select cells in row and change attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a link in one of the cells. I would like to change the "contenteditable" attribute to "true" (if it exist, not the last 2 cells for example) for each cell in the same row when you click the "edit" link for that row. I believe I am close thanx to other articles here on SO. Any suggestions? Thank you muchly in advance.

```js
function edit_me(e) {
        $.each(this.cells, function () {
            $(this).attr("contenteditable", "true");
        });
    }
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="7">
    <tr>
    <th>col 1 </th>
    <th>col 2 </th>
    <th>col 3 </th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td contenteditable="false">1</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">2</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">3</td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="edit_me(this)">edit</a></td>
    <td>delete</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td contenteditable="false">1</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">2</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">3</td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="edit_me(this)">edit</a></td>
    <td>delete</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Let me know if none of the answers worked or you still need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make `e` a `jQuery` object by wrapping in `$()`
2. Use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the children with attribute `contenteditable`

```js
function edit_me(e) {

    $.each($(e).closest('tr').find('[contenteditable]'), function() {
      $(this).attr("contenteditable", "true");
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellpadding="7">
  <tr>
    <th>col 1</th>
    <th>col 2</th>
    <th>col 3</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="false">1</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">2</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">3</td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="edit_me(this)">edit</a>
    </td>
    <td>delete</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="false">1</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">2</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">3</td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="edit_me(this)">edit</a>
    </td>
    <td>delete</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update**

There is no need for `$.each`, you can simply do

```
function edit_me(e) {
  $(e).find('[contenteditable]').attr("contenteditable", "true");
}
```

Comment: `$(e).parent().parent()` can be used in place of `$(e).closest('tr')`, and it may be faster, since you tell it explicitly which DOM node you want rather than making it search.  Also, `$.each` is not necessary here—you can simply write `.find('[contenteditable]').attr('contenteditable', 'true');`.

Comment: @BradleyGaragan, I like your second suggestion, thanks. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Change these:

```
onclick="edit_me(event)"
```

And try this:

```
function edit_me(e)
{
    $(e.target).closest('tr').children('td').attr("contenteditable", "true");
}
```